# Simple example of isotypical bundles without bundle maps between them?

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

What is a simple example of two bundles $\begin{smallmatrix}X\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix},\begin{smallmatrix}Y\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix}$ with homeomorphic fibers which admit no bundle map $\begin{smallmatrix}X\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix}\to\begin{smallmatrix}Y\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix}$?

I just realized I can't think of such a thing, but feel such creatures should exist when right bundle has no global section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where $X \to U$ and $Y \to U$ are covering maps of the same degree $n$ (so their fibers are finite sets of size $n$). If all the spaces involved are connected then they correspond to two subgroups of $\pi_1(U)$ of index $n$, and any bundle map between them is necessarily an isomorphism of covers, which means the corresponding subgroups are conjugate.

So it suffices to exhibit a group $\pi_1(U)$ and two non-conjugate subgroups of $\pi_1(U)$ of the same finite index. There are many such examples, e.g. if $U$ is the wedge of two circles then $\pi_1(U) \cong F_2$ has three subgroups of index $2$ all of which are normal and hence none of which are conjugate.

Comment: Forgive me for the hastle, but I have added edited in another question.

Comment: @Arrow: that seems like a pretty different question. I'd expect that under reasonable circumstances a bundle map inducing fiberwise homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, and that counterexamples would occur for annoying point-set topological reasons if they occur at all.

Comment: I will edit the question to its original format and ask the new one separately. Thanks.

Comment: I asked my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2477489/223002).