# Bundle map inducing isomorphism on fibers - when is it an isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Suppose $\begin{smallmatrix}X\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix}\to\begin{smallmatrix}Y\\ \downarrow\\ U \end{smallmatrix}$ is a bundle map inducing homeomorphisms on fibers.

1. What are some general conditions for this map to be a bundle isomorphism?
2. What is an example of such a map which is not a bundle isomorphism?
3. Is this map always an isomorphism when restricting to the category of locally connected spaces?

**Edit.** The bundles are not assumed locally trivial. Assume also the base $U$ is connected.

Comment: Can one manufacture trivial counterexamples when $U$ is not connected?

Comment: @Neal I welcome all examples, but I would really like to see an example "without cheating", and general conditions precluding it. Particularly I would like to see whether they must indeed arise from ["annoying point-set topological reasons"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477441/simple-example-of-isotypical-bundles-without-bundle-maps-between-them#comment5118664_2477448).
I will edit my question to explicitly prefer a connected base.

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y$ are trivial bundle, say $X = Y = U \times F $ then your map is on the form $(u,\lambda) \mapsto (u,\lambda,f_u(\lambda))$ where $f : U \to \text{Homeo}(F)$ is a continuous map. It is clear that this map is invertible with inverse $(u,f_u^{-1}(\lambda))$.

For the general case, we want to see if $f$ is an homeomorphism i.e if $f^{-1}$ is continuous, but continuity is a local condition so by the previous paragraph you are done.

Comment: By "bundle" I do not mean only locally trivial bundles. Just continuous maps.

Comment: So you have map $X \to U, Y \to U$ and you want to ask if any map $X \to Y$ commuting with the projection which induces isomorphism on the fiber is itself an isomorphism right ?

Comment: Yep, exactly. $\;$

Comment: Locally trivial bundles and - I think - local homeomorphisms always reflect isomorphy from fibers, but I wonder what can be said in the general case and what can go wrong.

Comment: Yes local homeomorphism should also work (which are also locally trivial fiber bundle if the projection is proper). I have to admit me too I have no ideas about the general case, but I'll try to think about a counter-example for see what kind of problems could arise.

Comment: [It seems](https://mathoverflow.net/a/280968/69037) this is a not an easy problem even for fiber bundles.

Comment: @Arrow : indeed, I would still be curious to see a counter-example with say manifolds.